# Shiny works locally but fails in production in weird manner

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

I have `leaflet` map in shiny dashboard with points. Clicking on some point, you will get text string from one column of main df `botsad.final` and subset of data from the SAME df, that should appear in the table below the map.

So:
1. Locally both text and table appear fine.
2. In production through [shinyapps.io](https://janzeero.shinyapps.io/bot_test/), text appears good, but table doesnt work. It produces error.
3. The df `botsad.final` is in directory of project and is same for `textOutput` (working) and `tableOutput` (working only locally).

Where is an error for deploying?
There is [a part of](https://github.com/Janzeero-PhD/Botanical-Garden-of-NULES/blob/master/server.R) `server.R` related to `tableOutput`. `ui.R` [is here](https://github.com/Janzeero-PhD/Botanical-Garden-of-NULES/blob/master/ui.R).

```
# Make a table with ecosystem services
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(data_of_click$clickedMarker)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    return(
      subset(botsad.final %>%
               dplyr::select(7:12, 14), 
             id == data_of_click$clickedMarker$id
      )
    ) 
  }, na = '-', bordered = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any error messages in the logs? I have not worked with leaflet maps in R, but I have deployed some applications to shinyapps.io. Please forgive my possibly unhelpful answer.

I had a look through the code, but could not run it (I think because I did not have the data).

My guess is that two things could be going wrong:

(1) the data is not being copied to the server. When you are deploying to R shiny, is the data in a file being deployed?

(2) the data is not being read on the server. Are you reading in the data in a global.R file or something?

If you are sure the data is on there, share what ever the logs are telling you.

Comment: File like global.R was deployed. Since clicking on the any icon as I mentioned above, even in prod works fine producing textOutput from that df. But it doesnt work in the prod (but works locally) with tableOutput! It hurts :(

Comment: You can find ui.R and server.R in the links above. Also I provided Garden.R with reproducible code for creating df botsad.final. Please download by yourself all files like bot1, bot2, bot3, bot4 and botsad.species, since I cannot just paste links on these (csv with Cyrillic letters and xlsx file). Also download icons and put them into subdirectory like 'www'. So downloading all of that and running whole app, you will see whats wrong. I suggest something doesnt refer properly for shinyapps.io in the piece of code written above, in the topic-starting post.

Comment: Scott, can you help me? I guess there is an other way to call subset in the table than I mentioned above, in the topic starting post. Please see this [app](https://janzeero.shinyapps.io/bot_test/): clicking on the icon of tree, you will see the text in the left corner, but table below map fails, although both outputs are from 1 df and work fine locally.